# VS2017 RC 2 csproj file location

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying the updated visual studio (VS2017 RC 2) with .net core functionalities. I learned that MS team removed project.json and instead created csproj file. However when I created an empty .net core web project (I also created webapi project) no csproj file is created within the project. Am I missing something, where is the csproj file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have VS2017 RC installed and I can see *WebApi.csproj* files (WebApi is the name of my project). It is located as expected in the root of the project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @konrad-viltersten. Why cannot I see WebApi.csproj  file in the solution explorer, do I have to make configuration in the visual studio? And finally, is WebApi.csproj correct file to add dependencies?

Comment: @tempx Not sure why **you** can't see it. How is the solution/project being scaffolded? Did you use Yeoman or the default wizard in VS?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @konrad-viltersten. I am using the default VS wizard.

Comment: @tempx Weird. Can you check the exact version (major, minor, revision) of the build for your VS17, please? I'll make sure to retrace the steps in mine.

Comment: Hi @konrad-viltersten. Versions are as follows: 

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 RC
Version 15.0.25928.0 D15REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Comment: @tempx You mention in your question that you run Core but the version you mention here is 4.6 (wheras Core is 5.x). Could it be something like that? I'm not entirely sure at the moment. The rest of the configuration is equivalent on my system.

Comment: yes you are right, the version also took my attention. I did not select the .net core for runtime environment. May be the problem is that. I will create a project using .net core environment soon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't see in solution explorer of the project that I created using VS2017 Community edition. I used the `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` template. However, I can see the `csproj` file in Windows Explorer under the root folder of the project as you've shown in your image. **But**, if I open this file in VS2017, it opens the entire project and not just the file.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone needs the same answer for macOS, in Visual Studio for Mac, right-click the project file (child of "master") in the Solution pane. Choose "Tools", then "Edit File".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What I often in Visual Studio 2017 RC3 to edit the csproj file, is:
Right click on the project title in the Solution Explorer window. Select the option "Edit [project name].csproj" to open the csproj file in the code editor window.

Answer (score 3):

The file is not showing, but if you select a project, right click on it, there is a menu called "Edit MyNetCore.csproj"